# How to get all files list from a relative URI in XAML application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, directory, relative-path

How to get all files from a folder in XAML application using relative path?

I am playing with a Kinect application built in WPF. All images used in the application are in 
`[project dir]\Images\` and all backgrounds are in 
`[project dir]\Images\Backgrounds\`.

I want to get list of all the images from Backgrounds directory using relative path. I have tried

```
DirectoryInfo(@"\Images\Backgrounds\").GetFiles();
```

but it says that Backgrounds directory must exist in `[full path+project dir]\debug\bin\`

Selecting each image manually works fine

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"Images\Backgrounds\Background1.png", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource imgsource = new BitmapImage(uri);
this.Backdrop.Source = imgsource;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for a single file because you specify URI to resource embedded in the assembly and not some folder on your drive, whilst `GetFiles()` will work only on a specific physical  folder. So either you need to copy all your images instead of embedding them or use the code below and `resourceNames` should give you names of all resources that you can reference by URI in your project:

```
List<string> resourceNames = new List<string>();
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var rm = new ResourceManager(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g", assembly);
try
{
    var list = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in list)
        resourceNames.Add((string)item.Key);
}
finally
{
    rm.ReleaseAllResources();
}
```

if you need then at this point each `item.Value` contains `UnmanagedMemoryStream` for each resource.

Comment: The Kinect applicaiton I am working on is GreenScreen sample of Kinect SDK v1.5. I am just trying to change the backgrounds with code.

Comment: "It works for a single file because you specify URI to resource embedded in the assembly" how it is embedded? None of these images are added in "Resources" (in Visual Studio). The URI is relative.

Comment: @LifeH2O, don't you have these files added to project? Do they display in VisualStudio in solution tree?

Comment: I found that the images are added to resource. I can see that when I set the source of background by clicking the Source button. The path is displayed as "/GreenScreen-WPF;component/Images/Backgrounds/Background.png"

Comment: @LifeH2O: hence your URI for a single file is working because it's not a real folder. In your solution you can change what it will do with images and if you set `Build Action` to `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` then VS will not embed images but copy them to physical output directory and  your `GetFiles()` will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I would reply to your post instead of posting a solution, but I'm new to this site and dont have that privledge yet.... Hey! Just trying to help.

Anyway, I've had a problem similar to this before concerning DirectoryInfo. Can't remember exactly how I solved it, but I remember the backslashes being tricky. Have you checked out the MSDN site? It seems like it can't find your directory so its looking for it in debug by default. MSDN says the format should be "MyDir\MySubdir" in C#.